# How to make autoGenerated filed inside Embedded Key in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Embeddable
public class ExamGroupId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String year;
    private Integer semesterNumber;
    private String semesterFacultyId;
    
    

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long autoGeneratedId;

}
```

@GeneratedValue gives Null and I need this field only to be auto-generated in a sequence way, is it possible?

Comment: I've removed the tags [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:postgresql]] as they conflict; if your question is about one of then, [edit] it accordingly.

Comment: The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id annotation, so try to add the `Id` annotation.